# c++ Programme compiled successfully but unable to run

Tags: command-line, compiling, c++

I compiled the program using gpp it was done successfully but when I tried to run the program I got these errors:-

I have included `using namespace std;` in 3'rd line

```
harish@harish-Lenovo-G580:~$ gpp iget.cpp -o abc
harish@harish-Lenovo-G580:~$ gpp -o abc iget.cpp
harish@harish-Lenovo-G580:~$ ./abc
./abc: line 3: using: command not found
./abc: line 5: struct: command not found
./abc: line 14: syntax error near unexpected token `('
./abc: line 14: `void getno()'
```

Comment: can we see the source code?

Comment: #include<iostream.h>

using namespace std;

struct inode
{
   int ino;
   struct inode *nxt;
   struct inode *flst;   
  
  }*hsq[4]={NULL},*frl=NULL;
    

void getno()
{
  int n;
  char a='a';

Comment: this is starting portion upto line 17

Answer (score 4):

You need to use `g++` not `gpp` e.g.

```
g++ -o abc iget.cpp
```

`gpp` is a pre-processor - not a compiler. It doesn't actually compile your code, and when you try to run `./abc` the shell is likely trying to interpret the pre-processed source code as a sequence of shell commands (which are 'not found').